# PowerApps: Lock dropdown options

Tags: sharepoint, dropdown, powerapps

I generated a PowerApps from an existing SharePoint list and I have a Choice column which has been automatically converted to a dropdown list on the app's Edit screen. The issue I'm having is that the app lets the user "edit" the dropdown list and they can type something else other than the premade choices.

Is it possible to make the dropdown read-only? I have several fields that rely on its selection for visibility. For some reason I couldn't find a property that lets me lock the choices. Am I missing something? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a PowerApps dorp down read only. To do so

1. Select the Edit Form in the screens side pane
2. Select the Data Source in the right panel
3. In the fields scroll to the field you want to make read only, and expand it
4. You  will get multiple options, select the view mode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally Form Controls on the Edit Screen that PowerApps auto creates are set to D**isplayMode.Edit.**

Then on the Details Screen the Form Controls are set to **DisplayMode.View.**

You can select ANY Form Control on ANY screen and set its DisplayMode Property to View to make the Control view-only.